# converting JSON to CSV file

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I've been on here a few times but cant seem to fix it. I'm trying to covert JSON to a CSV file. I keep on getting this error:
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None  JSONDecodeError: Expecting value.
Please help.
This is the code I'm trying to use.

```
import json 
import pandas as pd 

# load json object
with open('C:/Users/gavin/OneDrive/Desktop/4th Year/DAD project/mass.json', 'r') as f:
   d = json.load(f)

multi = []; inner = {}

def recursive_extract(i):
    global multi, inner

    if type(i) is list:
        if len(i) == 1:
            for k,v in i[0].items():
                if type(v) in [list, dict]:
                    recursive_extract(v)
                else:                
                    inner[k] = v
        else:
            multi = i

    if type(i) is dict:
        for k,v in i.items():
            if type(v) in [list, dict]:
                recursive_extract(v)
            else:                
                inner[k] = v

recursive_extract(d['data'])

data_dict = []
for i in multi:    
    tmp = inner.copy()
    tmp.update(i)
    data_dict.append(tmp)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
df.to_csv('Output.csv')
```

Update: This is the JSON that I'm trying to turn into a CSV file. I had to delete some records so that stack overflow would let me post my question.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "value": 4070,
      "data_year": 1998,
      "month_num": 0,
      "key": "Unknown"
    },
    {
      "value": 1095,
      "data_year": 1992,
      "month_num": 0,
      "key": "Unknown"
    },
    {
      "value": 11277,
      "data_year": 2017,
      "month_num": 0,
      "key": "Unknown"
    },
      {
      "value": 3481,
      "data_year": 1993,
      "month_num": 0,
      "key": "Unknown"
    },
    {
      "value": 9402,
      "data_year": 2013,
      "month_num": 0,
      "key": "Unknown"
    },
    {
      "value": 473,
      "data_year": 1991,
      "month_num": 0,
      "key": "Unknown"
    },
    {
      "value": 9587,
      "data_year": 1998,
      "month_num": 0,
      "key": "None"
    },
    {
      "value": 244,
      "data_year": 1992,
      "month_num": 0,
      "key": "None"
    }
],
"precise_data": []
}
```

Comment: Could you add a snippet of json file?

Comment: Just added some of it there.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the pandas inbuilt functionality to read a json file to a pandas dataframe

```
df=pd.read_json("temp.json")
```

once the file is read , you can save it as a csv file by

```
df.to_csv('temp.csv' , index = False)
```

If that doesn't work ,

you could try any one of the following , to read the json according to its structure

```
data= pd.read_json('Data.json', lines=True)
data= pd.read_json('Data.json', lines=True, orient='records') 
data= pd.read_json('Data.json', orient=str)
```

Comment: Just tried that and got this error:  loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None

ValueError: Expected object or value

Comment: Are you sure taht your json is not malformed , if not , you could try any of the following like data= pd.read_json('Data.json', lines=True)
data= pd.read_json('Data.json', lines=True, orient='records')
data= pd.read_json('Data.json', orient=str)

Comment: The second one seemed to fix that problem but now its giving me a key error but the key is right.